# Python copy files similar to xcopy

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to replicate the following xcopy functionality in Python:

```
xcopy \src\*.txt \dst /s /y /d:%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
```

In the example, xcopy is crawling a directory tree and copying the folder and any file that was created today. If a folder doesn't have a file that was created today then it doesn't copy that folder.

I tried playing around with shutil.copytree, but I couldn't figure out how to make the date stuff work. Am I just going to have to crawl the whole thing? There are currently over 2,200 folders and up to 2,000 files in a folder - so I'm worried about performance.

Comment: It's a little hard for me to tell exactly what you're asking. Maybe the question needs to be narrowed down or split into separate highly specific questions (in which case there could very well be existing Q&A answering those questions). As for your performance concern, I'd personally encourage you to either benchmark yourself, or research possible different solutions so you can ask an informed question about how they differ in terms of performance.

Comment: You can use `os.walk` to walk the tree and then `os.stat` to get the dates. Find the ones you like and `shutil.copy` one at a time.

Comment: As for speed, the actually copy will end up being the slowest part. The platform's copy utility (copy for windows, cp for linux) will likely be faster than shutil.copy. So use, subprocess.run for that.